# Accessing and modifying task_pt_regs in Linux Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

my question is about accessing and modifying pt_regs struct from a kernel module; I successfully get the register values of it using

```
task = pid_task(find_vpid(pid), PIDTYPE_PID);
```

to get the task_struct and

```
regs = task_pt_regs(tasks);
```

However, my questions are:

1. When I print out the values in the pt_regs, say

```
printk(KERN_INFO, "rax%llu\n", regs->ax);
```

every time I got the same value for all the registers. To make sure the process does updating its PCB, I tried to move it from core to core constantly using sched_affinity() so that it will actually do context switch during migration.

2. If I want to change the register value of a pt_regs, say I want to change RAX to 0, can I just code like:

```
 regs->ax = 0;
```

And if I write the correct values of what I recorded from the user process, can I successfully get a jump back?

Thanks for the help.

I tried to "force" my user process to switch context by migrating it from cores to cores, but it doesn't work. I also tried to write 0 to regs->ip, it caused an error.

Comment: Do you somehow "pause" the thread before working with its registers? If the thread is active its registers are contained.. inside actual registers, and other core definitely cannot access them.

Comment: I did not. Can I actually do that in a kernel module? Like "pause" a thread, changing the register values and resume its execution? Like a manually context switch?

Comment: I don't know. May be, you could be able to send some signal to the process, so it will be interrupted.